# Can't make android studio identify PercentageRelativeLayout

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-percentrelativelayout

I'm trying to use PercentRelativeLayout but gradle won't find the fine the relevant resource identifier.

This is my layout (simple item in list view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true">


    <ImageView
        app:layout_widhtPercent="30%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/projects_lv_item_image" />

    <TextView
        app:layout_widhtPercent="60%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/projects_lv_item_title" />
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

This is my builde.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devlopers.yemima.kh1"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.1.1'


}
```

And this is the error I'm getting from Android Studio:

```
Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_widhtPercent' in package 'com.devlopers.yemima.kh1'
```

Your help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

You spelled it wrong: it isn't `layout_wid**ht**Percent` but `layout_widthPercent`